# PayPal OpenID access token missing requested entries

Tags: paypal, openid-connect

I have a server resident JVM-based (Clojure, specifically) application that has a working OpenID Connect client implementation, that allows me to successfully authenticate my users against Google and Microsoft's OpenID Connect services.  I am trying to configure the application to support PayPal's ersatz OpenID Connect, and am encountering a number of issues.

I have:

1. Created and successfully saved the application in the PayPal developer dashboard (name, return URL, privacy & terms links, permissions needed, etc).
2. Configured both Live and Sandbox entries in my application's configuration, using the correct application id and application secret information from the dashboard.
3. Specified for both Live and Sandbox that I want to grant access solely for full name and email.

For both Live and Sandbox, I can:

- Redirect from my server to the PayPal authorize workflow (i.e., https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize or https://www.paypal.com/signin/authorize -- it doesn't seem to matter which I use for Live)
- Interactively grant permission to my app to access my (personal account in the case of Live, sandbox "buyer" in the case of Sandbox) profile information.

At this point, the Live instance returns a genericError screen, with no useful information.  The PayPal dashboard's API calls screen says I've made no recent calls.

On the other hand, Sandbox redirects back to my app with an authorization code, and I'm able to use that code to request an id_token.  The scope parameter that I provide includes `openid`, `profile`, and `email`.  The response to this includes the expected `id_token`.  However, while the normal (jose4j) procedure for verifying this JWT token doesn't work (the verification selector doesn't find a valid key), I'm able to try each of the keys in the PayPal jwks key set, and one of them does work to verify the JWT.

The decoded JWT, however, is missing the information I expect.  The keys of the JWT that I get back are:

- `auth_time`
- `exp`
- `sub`
- `iss`
- `session_index`

Given that I granted profile and email access, and requested profile and email in the scope, I expected to get name and email address in the JWT, but they are not there.

So, I'm left with three questions:

1. How to debug genericError from the authorize workflow?
2. How to get email and name information from the token service?
3. Why do Live and Sandbox behave differently?

Any hints on these would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer to retrieving email and name information on PayPal.  It looks like the right workflow is to:

1. Initially request an `authorization_code` instead of an `id_token` from the authorization endpoint,
2. Exchange that for an `access_token` through the token service, and then
3. Use the userinfo endpoint to fetch user information with the access token as Bearer authorization.

This is certainly documented in PayPal's developer info, but it's unlike Microsoft and Google's implementations of OpenID Connect, and more like OAuth2, as I (badly) understand it.

However, while this allows me now to get email from the Sandbox implementation, I still get a generic error rather than a callback from the Live authorization endpoint, with no information to help diagnose that issue.